# Change a priority of a thread in other process

Tags: linux, pthreads

I am looking for a way to change a priority of a thread in another process.

For a simple example,

Let's say there are two processes A and B and each process has multiple threads 1, 2, and 3

What I want to do is changing the priority of a thread in process B from some thread in process A.

When I tried it with "pthread_setschedprio()" it outputs segmentation fault.

I think the segfault happens since processes are protected from one another.

Is there a way to change a priority of a thread in another process?

Thanks!

Comment: One process cannot (directly) manage the threads of another.  You need a new plan.

Comment: See also http://xyproblem.info/ -- what are you _actually_ trying to achieve?